# How to test in React Native Expo Android deep linking

Tags: android, react-native, expo, android-deep-link

I have a React Native Expo project. I have added a .well-known directory with `assetlinks.json` file:

```
[
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "*******",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
        "*********"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Also, I have in my `app.json`:

```
  "intentFilters": [
    {
      "action": "VIEW",
      "autoVerify": true,
      "data": [
        {
          "scheme": "http",
          "host": "192.168.1.13:19006",
          "pathPrefix": "/login"
        }
      ],
      "category": ["BROWSABLE", "DEFAULT"]
    }
  ]
```

But, if I do: `expo start`, and I open chrome in my android emulator and I type my local IP, it opens it through the web browser and not through the app. My linking prefix is `prefixes: [Linking.makeUrl("/")]`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? Also, could this handle login credential storing/autofill on android ?

Comment: To test it while launching it on Expo, you must use expo url `exp://192.168.1.13:19000/--/{screen-you-want-to-test}`. I've been using this website to generate a deeplink to be able to click on it https://halgatewood.com/deeplink/

If you follow the code I have on the question, it should work. Just replace your scheme if you're using https and the host to your domain, and that should be enough. Then, on your linking configuration file, you will need to add also your domain to the prefixes array: `["https://example.com", Linking.makeUrl("/")]`

Comment: Concerning the authentication flow, I've followed React Navigation Authentication Flow https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Ill look into this in more detail when I get back to this issue, but I believe it answers what I need very well. Im particularly interested in autofill for android which mentions digital asset links https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-optimize#associate
Also expo's docs https://docs.expo.dev/guides/linking/#deep-links-on-android